# How to pass params from controller to Zend_Form?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-controller, zend-config, zend-loader

I know this question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496516/pass-a-variable-from-zend-controller-to-zend-form). But this doesnt work for me. 
The Form is generated by using the PluginLoader:

```
$formClass = Zend_Registry::get('formloader')->load('Payment');
$form = new $formClass(array('someval' => $my_arr));
```

Payment.php:

```
class Form_Payment extends Zend_Form
{

   protected $_someval = array();

   public function init()
   {
      $this->setAction('payment/save');
      //....
      $this->addElement('multiCheckbox', 'store_id', array('label' => 'Someval:', 'required' => true, 'multiOptions' => $this->getSomeval()))
   }

   public function setSomeval($someval) {
      $this->_someval = $someval;
   }

   public function getSomeval() {
      return $this->_someval;
   }
}
```

As I can see the load method only returns the class name, so `new $formClass();` is equal `new Form_Payment()` but why this isn't accept params?

Comment: `Zend_Registry::get('formloader')` is this a custom plugin?. Can you post that code too.

Comment: You aren't passing any params. What do you want to pass to the form?

Comment: @NandakumarV `Zend_Registry::get('formloader')` load the Form_Payment

@Phil I edited the code above, so this should be clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way by myself. **I was looking for a way to inject some params while my Zend_Form was initialised.** It seems the only way for this is to pass the params to the constructor - which is executed before the init method.

```
class Form_Payment extends Zend_Form
{

   private $_someval;

   public function __construct(array $params = array())
   {
       $this->_someval = $params['someval'];
       parent::__construct();
   }

   public function init()
   {
      $this->setAction('payment/save');
      //....
      $this->addElement('multiCheckbox', 'store_id', 
         array('label' => 'Someval:', 
               'required' => true, 
               'multiOptions' => $this->_someval // passed params now available
         )) 
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add custom function to your form class like

```
class Form_Payment extends Zend_Form
{
     public function init()
     {
          $this->setAction('payment/save');
          // and so on
     }

     public function doSome()
     {
          $this->setAction('other/action');
     }
}
```

and call it after instanciating form in controller

```
$form = new $formClass();
$form->doSome();
```

Comment: Or you know, just call `$form->setAction('other/action')`. `Zend_Form::setAction()` is a public method

Comment: I meant it in general, if form already has public methods - you should use them :)

Comment: @Vadyus but values must be known to the init method